# Why does not ldd output the libraries that I have linked when generating the executable file?

Tags: lapack, blas, atlas

I have linked the project with ATLAS library, `-llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lgfortran`, and it could compile successfully. But when I use the `ldd` command to view the dependency libraries, the output is as follows:

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Desktop/qt_output$ldd test_atlas
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa99ff000)
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /home/ubuntu/Documents/3rdparty/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007fe0577d7000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fe057477000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe057173000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe056e76000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe056c60000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe0568a1000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe056689000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe05646c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe056264000)
libcudart.so.5.0 => /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (0x00007fe056009000)
libnpp.so.5.0 => /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libnpp.so.5.0 (0x00007fe05051c000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fe0502e0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe057e31000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe0500db000)
    ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Desktop/qt_output$
```

Why does not it have the libatlas.so or libatlas.a? Thanks.

UPDATED:

```
   CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
   CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -std=c++0x -O2 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
   INCPATH       = -I../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../../Documents/3rdparty/include -I../../Documents/3rdparty/include/opencv2 -I../../Documents/3rdparty/include/opencv -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include  -I.
    LINK          = g++
    LFLAGS        = -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib
    LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)   -L/home/ubuntu/Documents/3rdparty/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lgfortran
```

Comment: There are two possibilities. Either these libraries are statically linked or no atlas function is called on main program. Could you give me full linking command?

Comment: Thanks, ctheo. I have linked the atlas with the libatlas.a, so I think it's the first possibility. I have updated the question for the full `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFAGS` parameters, please check it.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my respond below.

Comment: `linux-vdso.so.1` ,why the directory for this library is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker is looking for `.so` files in the system library paths and user defined paths (like `/home/ubuntu/Documents/3rdparty/lib/`). These `.so` files are defined by  `-l` argument. For example the `-latlas` corresponds to `libatlas.so`.

If `libatlas.so` file is not found then the linker will look for `libatlas.a`. This file is basically an `ar` (archive) file of all `.o` library files. The `.a` files are treated same as objects and are included inside the executable. So they do not appear in `ldd` command.

If you use `-static` argument with `g++` then you force the linker to look only for `.a` files and then `ldd` returns nothing.

In order to make dynamic link to `libatlas.so` you need to add this file in `/home/ubuntu/Documents/3rdparty/lib/`.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for so detail explanation.